# How to remove nested variable in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following values in the helm values files

```
http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        end-user:
          test: true
    route:
    - destination:
        host: apie
        service: 'svc-1'
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: api
        service: 'svc-2'
```

and would like to delete the `service` values using helm template

Comment: What have you tried already?  What does your template code look like?  The values content is something that can be provided by the user at deploy time; can you just delete the `service:` lines from the Helm value if you don't want them?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of helm with regard to removing keys has varied by version.

In some early versions of helm you could remove it from a child template this way:

```
http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        service: null
```

In some cases, this will still work. I'd recommend trying this first as it is the most straightforward if it supports your particular case.

In Helm 3.13.1, I have solved it this way:

In my child template, I set the key I want to remove to a unique value like this:

```
http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        service: nulledForRemoval
```

When running the `install`, `upgrade`, and `template` commands I pass the following additional flags `--post-renderer grep --post-renderer-args -v --post-renderer-args nulledForRemoval` as suggested [in issue 9027](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/9027#issuecomment-1487341841). The result is that my final chart has no `http:route:destination:service` key.